# understanding kernel oops error code

Tags: debugging, linux-kernel, kernel, panic

in kernel oops of ARM following logs are printed in kernel logs -

```
<1>[ 4205.112835] I[0:swapper/0:0] [c0] Unable to handle kernel paging request at virtual address ff898580 
<1>[ 4205.112874] I[0:swapper/0:0] [c0] pgd = ec3c4000 
<1>[ 4205.112901] I[0:swapper/0:0] [c0] [ff898580] *pgd=00000000 
<0>[ 4205.112939] I[0:swapper/0:0] [c0] Internal error: Oops: 80000005 #1] PREEMPT SMP ARM
```

Sometimes the oops this code is -

```
Internal error: Oops - undefined instruction: 0 [#1] PREEMPT SMP ARM
```

and in most of the logs it is -

```
Internal error: Oops: 5 [#1] PREEMPT SMP ARM
```

Can someone explain the purpose of this code and its meaning?

Comment: Could you provide the whole stacktrace? `undefined instruction` is quite strange. It means that the compiler converted your code to an instruction that the hardware does not support. This could however be something simple like disabled floating point operations. see http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0363g/Beijdcef.html

Answer (score 2):

The information you provided is quite few.

As in [arch/arm/kernel/traps.c](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/arm/kernel/traps.c#L242)

You will find

```
printk(KERN_EMERG "Internal error: %s: %x [#%d]" S_PREEMPT S_SMP S_ISA "\n", str, err, ++die_counter);
```

Actually whole stack trace will be much more helpful, you will find bug location and by disassembling to find real place in code.

Just guessing, you touched a NULL pointer ==